# Are there any examples on python-purple floating around?

Tags: python, libpurple

I want to learn it but I have **no** idea where to start. Everything out there suggests reading the `libpurple` source but I don't think I understand enough `c` to really get a grasp of it.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much about it yet... the [intro](http://brunoabinader.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-python-purple.html), the [howto](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/PythonHowTo), and the [sources](https://git.maemo.org/projects/python-purple/?p=python-purple;a=tree) (here browsing them online but of course you can git clone them) are about it. In particular, the tiny example client you can get from [here](https://git.maemo.org/projects/python-purple/?p=python-purple;a=blob_plain;f=nullclient.py;hb=HEAD) does have some miniscule example of use of purple's facilities (definitely not enough, but maybe it can get you started with the help of some 'dir', 'help' and the like...?)

Comment: the blog post is not available anymore, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much help this will be but based on information from [here](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/PythonHowTo), it seems like you just install python-purple and import and call the functions as normal Python functions.

Comment: the link was 3 years old so it's no surprise it linked to porn...it's been changed to reflect the original cause.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you with a concrete example as I decided to use something else.  However, one of the first things I wanted to do after I cloned the repo was remove the ecore dependency.  Here's a patch submitted to the mailing list to do just that: https://garage.maemo.org/pipermail/python-purple-devel/2009-March/000000.html

Incidentally, if you're looking for AIM take a look at twisted.words.  For Yahoo, trying getting the source for curphoo or zinc (both are console YMSG clients).  For GTalk/Jabber, I've had good experiences with xmpppy.